# Materialize side nav bar opening on one page - not working on page two

Tags: html, css, materialize, sidebar

I have searched every thread in the forums, and not be able to resolve my issue. I mostly believe this is because I am new to coding and perhaps don't understand it properly yet.

please help page two below is the one with this issue. The side nav does not work it does not open on the page with the code below. and also it does not close when you click back on the page.

```
   <body>
      <!-- Header -->
      <header class="main-header-inner">
          <div class="navbar-fixed">
        <nav class="transparent">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
              <img src="img/logo2.png">
              <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-nav" class="button-collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
              <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li>
                  <a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                  <li>
                      <a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="solutions.html">Solutions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="grey-text text-lighten-3 " href="index.html">About us</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <a href="https://be.linkedin.com/">
                         <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-1x grey-text text-lighten-3"></i></a>
                        </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            </nav>
          </div>

              <div>
                  <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-nav">
                    <h4 class="black-text text-darken-4 center">Lueur Tech</h4>
                    <li>
                      <div class="divider"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="index.html">
                        <i class="fa fa-home black-text text-darken-4"></i> Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <div class="divider"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="solutions.html">
                        <i class="fas fa-lightbulb fa-1x black-text text-lighten-3"></i> Solutions</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <div class="divider"></div>
                        </li>
                      <li>
                          <a href="index.html">
                          <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-1x black-text text-lighten-3"></i> About us</a>
                        </li>
                  </ul>
                  </div>
```

index page where there is no issue but I have crossed checked both codes and can't find anything different. The only issue I have is that it remains open unless you click a link and I would like it to close if you click back on the page.

```
    <body>
  <!-- Header -->
  <header class="main-header">
      <div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav class="transparent">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
         <img src="img/logo2.png">
          <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-nav" class="button-collapse">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li>
              <a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="solutions.html">Solutions</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a class="grey-text text-lighten-3 " href="#About">About us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://be.linkedin.com/">
                   <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-1x grey-text text-lighten-3"></i></a>
                  </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
        </nav>
        </div>

        <div>
          <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-nav">
            <h4 class="black-text text-darken-4 center">Lueur Tech</h4>
            <li>
              <div class="divider"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="index.html">
                <i class="fa fa-home black-text text-darken-4"></i> Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="divider"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="solutions.html">
                <i class="fas fa-lightbulb fa-1x black-text text-lighten-3"></i> Solutions</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <div class="divider"></div>
                </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#About">
                  <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-1x black-text text-lighten-3"></i> About us</a>
                </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
```

thank you for your help.

**UPDATE**: sideNav works in codepen.io/Bjorn_Ironside1986/pen/VRbyvL but doesn't work in codepen.io/Bjorn_Ironside1986/pen/OqmOdR

these 2 are required to see codepen working

```
<!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: please add a working fiddle.

Comment: whats a working fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you never close your header tag.

Comment: Thank you for your input. i have tried what you said the index page works fine by adding a close header tag it now closes when i click on the page. However the first block of code still does not work.

Comment: when i click on the this menu icon i get this in the address bar "http://127.0.0.1:5500/solutions.html#"

Comment: OK, that's because your link tag leads to nowhere:
`<a href="#" data-activates="mobile-nav" class="button-collapse">`

The href attribute must contain your destination, if you put
`<a href="/" data-activates="mobile-nav" class="button-collapse">`
the link will send you to the home page.

Alternatively, you can scroll to a specific element by giving href its id value:
`<a href="#id_of_your_target_element" data-activates="mobile-nav" class="button-collapse">`

Comment: Hi Armaud Strill, Thank you for your input, i understand what your are saying but.. the the code is identical on both pages and the home page works perfectly fine this is the page with the issue  codepen.io/Bjorn_Ironside1986/pen/OqmOdR

this is the home page where it works no problem. can you check and see what i have done wrong as they are identical. https://codepen.io/Bjorn_Ironside1986/pen/VRbyvL

Answer (score 1):

You need some javascript to initialize the sidenav - in the code below, i just added the options for the side nave to open from the left... Click on the Menu button on the left.

Hope it works for you.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
  var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems, {
    edge: 'left'
  });
});
```

```html
<!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<!-- Header -->
<header class="main-header-inner">
  <div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav class="transparent">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
          <img src="img/logo2.png">
          <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-nav" class="button-collapse">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
          <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li>
              <a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="solutions.html">Solutions</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="grey-text text-lighten-3 " href="index.html">About us</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="https://be.linkedin.com/">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-1x grey-text text-lighten-3"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div>
    <ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
      <li>
        <div class="user-view">
          <div class="background">
            <img src="images/office.jpg">
          </div>
          <a href="#user"><img class="circle" src="images/yuna.jpg"></a>
          <a href="#name"><span class="white-text name">John Doe</span></a>
          <a href="#email"><span class="white-text email">jdandturk@gmail.com</span></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="divider"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html">
          <i class="fa fa-home black-text text-darken-4"></i> Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="divider"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="solutions.html">
          <i class="fas fa-lightbulb fa-1x black-text text-lighten-3"></i> Solutions</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="divider"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html">
          <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-1x black-text text-lighten-3"></i> About us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger">
      <h4 class="black-text text-darken-4 center">Lueur Tech</h4>
    </a>
  </div>


  <!-- Showcase -->
  <div class="showcase container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m10 offset-m1 center">
        <h1>The Digital World</h1>
        <h5>Solutions</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<!-- Section: Solutions About -->
<section class="section section-solutions-about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m5">
        <h2>What We Do...</h2>
        <p>Solutions are ways of solving problems, when you consider world issues today, everything boils down to Langauge, Maths, Technology and Science! If you consider what these represent, in one view that could be taken if we break them down it is merely
          code in some form, structed together to create innovation.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m6 offset-m1">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">
            <ul class="tabs">
              <li class="tab col s4">
                <a href="#tab1" class="purple-text">Web Devlopment</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Section: Features -->
<section class="section section-features grey lighten-3">
  <div class="container center">
    <h4>
      <span class="deep-purple-text text-darken-1 center">Powerful</span> & Innovative</h4>
    <h6 class="grey-text text-darken-2 center">We aim to assist you, and provide quality of service to help you scale your business, capture new clients and retain existing customers with our desings!</h6>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- Row 1 -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <h5>
          <i class="fa fa-user"></i> User Friendly Applications
        </h5>
        <p>As a business the focus is on the client and the user to generate interest or purchase of services and products. We focus on functionality and accessability at the forefront of every desgin to ensure the user maintains interest. We ask you to
          provide the information needed to explain your product or service which will allow the user to make an informed choice.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <h5>
          <i class="fa fa-database"></i> Security of user and client Data
        </h5>
        <p>In today's society information is the new form of gold. We can advise you on policys such as EU GDPR and UK data protection laws. Depedning on your wesbites structure we will inform you of any products which may be of benfit to prevent cyber crime.
          </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <h5>
          <i class="fa fa-chart-line"></i> Data Analytics
        </h5>
        <p>
          Data helps devlope a business it can show growing trends or point out possible issues. With this information a business can takes steps to proctect both themsleves and their client but also it can assist them in devloping growth and expanding into new
          sectors. We can advise on tools which can be helpful to your business in relation gathering data from users.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Row 2 -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <h5>
          <i class="fa fa-github"></i> Problem Solving
        </h5>
        <p>
          Programing is not for everyone, that is why their are expereinced devlopers who offer services such a repair or managing sites. We can offer sulutions to problems with your site should the need arise. In some circumstances we may offer to manage your
          site for a fee, this can be discussed further dpending your needs.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <h5>
          <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add-ons
        </h5>
        <p>Our main service is devlopment, we dont offer hosting services or provide domain names. We can put you in touch with some providers, depending on your business services. We dont offer graphic design. We source images which are free of royalty
          and are licenced for commecial use to prevent any legal or copyright issues. But sometimes we have to use images from sources such as adobe stock therefore these are not free and will be added to the final invoice. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <h5>
          <i class="fas fa-desktop"></i> Website Design
        </h5>
        <p> We can offer a range of services in relation to desgin and devlopment. We can do "Landing Page" Mulitiple Page Design, One page design with different sections and E-commerce sites with a database. We can also build custome designs, all our projects
          take time depending on complexity and nature of the project.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="center">

      <h5>
        <span class="deep-purple-text text-lighten-1">Have a question? </span> Contact our sales team
      </h5>
      <p>sales@lueurtech.co.uk</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="page-footer black lighten-1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col l6 s12">
        <h5 class="white-text">About Us</h5>
        <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">Our company name "Lueur" is a french word which translates to "Glow" the more common use of the word is "lueur d'espoir" which means "Glimmer of Hope" it is in this meaning that our business looks to offer small business the chance to glow. We
          take into consideration that everyone just wants to succeed in life and in business so our mission of course is to make a stable business but the main prespective is to give hope and help people grow!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col l4 offset-l2 s12">
        <h5 class="white-text">Links</h5>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a class="grey-text text-lighten-3 " href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="solutions.html">Solutions</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="index.html">About us</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-copyright deep-purple darken-1">
    <div class="container">
      <div> Lueur Tech &copy; 2018</div><i class="fab fa-cc-paypal fa-3x grey-text text-lighten-3"></i>
      <a href="https://be.linkedin.com/">
        <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-3x grey-text text-lighten-3"></i></a>
      <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4 right  " href="#!"> Terms | Legal | Privacy</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: thank you for your input i already have the " <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"> at the bottom of the page on both pages and the other page works fine. if i scroll down the page and click the menu icon it takes me back to the top of the page. 



perhaps ill put it in codepen https://codepen.io/Bjorn_Ironside1986/pen/OqmOdR

maybe you can see where i went wrong on this page as it works fine on the other page.

Comment: @BjörnIronside, kindly check

Comment: hello thank you again for coming to my aid.

'sorry not sure what i am checking as i ran you code snippet and it doesn't work.

he the code is identical on both pages and the home page works perfectly fine this is the page with the issue codepen.io/Bjorn_Ironside1986/pen/OqmOdR this is the home page where it works no problem. can you check and see what i have done wrong as they are identical. codepen.io/Bjorn_Ironside1986/pen/VRbyvL – | thank you

Comment: theexact issue that you're facing is that sideNav works in https://codepen.io/Bjorn_Ironside1986/pen/VRbyvL but doesn't work in https://codepen.io/Bjorn_Ironside1986/pen/OqmOdR... am I correct?

Comment: yes thank you for your patience with me. the code on both pages are the same unless i have overlooked something. i need to know what is wrong for me to be able to progress my understanding of coding, changing the code to some other format will not give me the answer of why it doesn't work on one page but does the other so therefore i wont know for future.  thank you kindly for your help.

Comment: on the code which is working... what do you click to open the side nav?

Comment: the menu icon when the page in med- size or below.

Comment: I gotta catch some rest - updated the question and added tags which should make this more searchable - hope you find what you're looking for